# MVC html helper to generate enum drop down list dynamiclly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

My model is:

```
public class DynamicEnum
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Value {get; set;}
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public DynamicEnum DynamicEnum {get; set;}
}

Public ActionResult MyAction
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.DynamicEnum = new DynamicEnum(){ Name = "System.DayOfWeek", Value = 2};
    return View(model);
}
```

So in the view I need a HtmlHelper to dynamically generate DropDownListFor like:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.DynamicEnum)
```

I used MVC 5.2.3, Does any one have any idea?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? `Html.EnumDropDownListFor` is built-in since MVC 5.2

Comment: The built-in method expects an instance of the enum to be passed as the expression property. The OP needs a little bit more dynamic behavior here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to use reflection:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, DynamicEnum>> expression)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        var dynamicEnum = (DynamicEnum)metadata.Model;
        var enumType = Type.GetType(dynamicEnum.Name, true);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new Exception(dynamicEnum.Name + " doesn't represent a valid enum type");
        }

        // TODO: You definetely want to cache the values here to avoid the expensive
        // reflection call: a ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IList<SelectListItem>> could be used
        var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
        var values = enumNames.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x,
            Value = ((int)Enum.Parse(enumType, x)).ToString(),
        }).ToList();

        string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression) + ".Value";

        return html.DropDownList(name, values);
    }
}
```

Remark: The [`HtmlHelper.EnumDropDownListFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.enumdropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.EnumDropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D%29) extension method already exists in ASP.NET MVC so make sure that you bring the namespace in which you declared your custom extension method into scope to avoid collisions. Or just use a different method name.

Comment: I think it based on which version he is using. If 5.2 then it akready exists.

Comment: Yes, it already exists, I have added a Remark at the bottom of my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thank you. It's perfect, I just add Selected to SelectListItem, and I am just wondering as long as I used MVC 5.2.3 is there any way that in Custom Helper we return *EnumDropDownListFor* instead of *DropDownList*?

Comment: @Saeid, no unfortunately there's no way because this built-in helper expects an expression that returns a property of type `Enum` which you do not have. According to your requirements you have a custom view model with a string and value properties which must be transformed before being used. Also I really don't understand why you edited my answer and added this `Selected` property? The idea here is that the selected value will come from the integer `Value` property of the view model which is why I used the `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText` method.

Comment: That is to say that I am now reverting your changes back to what I initially wrote because that's not how I meant my answer to be used.